# Unable to import a library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

i am trying to import [this](https://github.com/alexfu/CountDownView) project as a library

First I downloaded and extracted the project and pasted it to the destination project. Then in the settings.gradle file I pasted this

```
include  'app',':subProject:CountDownViewmaster'
```

and removed the default app.

Then in the build.gradle file I wrote

```
compile project(':subProject:CountDownViewmaster')
```

It is giving me the error

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

What could be the solution

Comment: Why did you remove the default app? You should replace that `app` with your own `app` folder

Comment: sThe default was just "  include 'app'  " Should I add it back, and the both are to be included ??

Comment: Nevermind, that code isn't a proper Android library

Comment: any ideas for a good android library for adding countdown from fetching the value from the server?? I do not have a server setup

Comment: I don't understand why a server is necessary for your question

Answer (score 1):

Missing colon(:) before app. use below code

```
include  ':app',':subProject:CountDownViewmaster'
```

**Update**

1.Download the project and paste it on desktop.

2.In Android studio select `File->New->ImportModule` and give the path of the location of the project, name of the module and click finish.

3.Now add `compile project(':modulename')` in gradle .

Comment: Thanks for answering.it is still giving the same output

Comment: did u try importing the project as module in android studio? Is that project is fully copied into the root location of your project?